# Weird indentation error [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am coding and when I tried to print out a certain line from a text file , it would keep on giving me an indentation error.But when I indent it , it gives me invalid syntax.EDIT= THE CODE WORKS WHEN I REMOVE `IF GTIN == 86947367:`, BUT WHY ?

```
if GTIN == 86947367 :
    fp = open("read_it")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if i == 0:

    elif i == 2:

    fp.close()
```

Comment: Which of the two versions is the above code? It would help if you documented those two approaches separately (after of course extracting a minimal example) and also provided the verbatim error messages separately.

Comment: what is the EXACT "weird error" log?

Answer (score 2):

Correct indentation for your code will be:

```
if GTIN == 86947367:
    fp = open("read_it")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if i == 0:
        pass
    elif i == 2:
        pass
fp.close()
```

Make sure you don't mix <kbd>TAB</kbd> with spaces as it will ruin your indentation altogether.

Comment: thank you , I used tab but why do I need pass after if i ==0:

Comment: @j.doe, python expects some code inside the `if` clause. if there is no such code, it will throw an `IndentationError`

Comment: You don't need to `pass`, it is just to show you how to indent correctly. You can put any statement inside instead of it

Comment: And it says fp is not defined why ?

Comment: Maybe because `if GTIN == 86947367:` is not `True`. Then your `fp` is undefined. Make sure that indeed `GTIN == 86947367`

Comment: when testing I used that code but it still says  undefined

Comment: That is impossible. Remove the `if GTIN == 86947367` and try again. (meaning that you **always** call `fp = open("read_it")`). That should work

Comment: Indentation of the for loop is still incorrect - as it will loop around the file even if the file is not opened. I assume that the comparison on the value of GTIN is important here (i.e the OP did intend to only open the file if the comparison is True).

Comment: The indentation is 100% correct. It is the OP's responsibility to make sure his file is opened.

Comment: I tested my file separately and reading from it was no problem

Answer (score 1):

The better indentation for your code I think is :

```
if GTIN == 86947367:
    fp = open("read_it")
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 0:
            pass
        elif i == 2:
            pass
    fp.close()
```

You always need your for loop, and your file closure indented at the same level as your 'open' statement, so that you loop over the file only if you have opened it

An even better solution would be :

```
if GTIN == 86947367:
    with open("read_it") as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == 0:
                 pass
            elif i == 2:
                 pass
```

Using 'with' ensures that your code will always close the file, even if an error occurs. It is good practice to use the 'with' when opening files or simiar - and you don't need to use 'close' as the 'with statement takes care of it automatically.

Comment: thanks you , so if I want to print lines 0 and 2 I just replace pass with print(i)

Comment: yes - that should work.

Comment: if you 'print(i)' it will print the line number - you might want to 'print(line)' which should - if you have the indentation right etc - print the actual line from the file.

Comment: I tried print(line) , it doesn't do anything I might be missing something , isn't there an easier way to print out a certain line from a text file

Comment: If your indentation is right - then that code should work - assuming the file exists - that the value of GTIN is right, the file has the right number of lines - you have the right permissions for the file etc.

Comment: Did you solve this problem - if so can you tick this answer to accept it.